# Determining which node in a Treeview has been clicked

Tags: c#, .net, treeview, treeviewitem

Is the "AfterSelected" event the best place to respond to a click on a node?

How do I determine which node has been clicked? The following code does not work, b ut rather tells me, "The name 'NodeBetter' does not exist in the current context"

```
private void treeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Node.Name == NodeBetter)
            {

            }
            // else NodeUh, NodeOze
        }
```

Comment: I believe using the MouseUp event and checking HitTest info may be what you are looking for: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z6sb88bz%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear what you expected `NodeBetter` to refer to, but [`TreeViewEventArgs.Node`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treevieweventargs.node.aspx) is indeed what you want. As per the documentation:

> Gets the tree node that has been checked, expanded, collapsed, or selected.

Perhaps you meant:

```
if (e.Node.Name == "NodeBetter")
```

?

It's not clear whether you *really* want the `Selected` event though. Would you want your handler to be called if the node were expanded but not selected, for example?

Comment: No, I don't need to know when it is expanded, only when the node is actually selected.

Comment: I thought this would be correct. I suggested an alternative using HitTest method. Either one should work fine though.

Comment: @ClayShannon: Okay, so `e.Node` is fine.